# dynamodb - Unable to stop duplicate entry in table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am retrying to restrict duplicate entry in dynamodb table based on one attribute, howerver failed to do so. Dynamodb table structure is as follows:

```
CustomerDetail, CreationDate, CustomerName, APIDescription

hash_key = CustomerDetail
range_key = CreationDate
```

Requirement is if similar CustomerDetail exists already in table, it should not perform insert. While inserting record I am trying to use ConditionalExpression as:

```
dynamodb.put_item(TableName=table_name, 
                  Item=item,
                  ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(CustomerDetail)")
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Why have a range key at all in that case?

Answer (score 0):

##### The issue

The reason you are still getting duplicates is because your condition is based on a different item. A condition is only evaluated against the item you are writing/updating. For example, lets imagine I have this item in my table:

| CustomerDetail | CreationDate | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-10-10T00:00 | Lee |

Now I want to write a new item, with the following information:

```
CustomerDetail=123
CreationDate=2023-10-16T23:00
CustomerName=Lee
```

and of course with our condition  `attribute_not_exists(CustomerDetail)`

Now what happens is DynamoDB checks if `CustomerDetail` exists for the item with `CustomerDetail=123` AND `CreationDate=2023-10-16T23:00`. But we know that item does not exist yet, so the condition evaluates to true and the write gets accepted.

##### The Solution

- One way to overcome this is to get rid of the sort key for your table, that means it will always evaluate against a single `CustomerDetail`.
- The second way involves the use of transactions, which can increase the cost of your DynamoDB usage. This is discussed thoroughly in this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/)